# how to apply ranking in teradata

Tags: teradata

I am currently working with multiple tables. table1 which is to be lookup with database. for ex. I have worked on excel sheet and updated records in the DB and now need to lookup with DB whether records have been updated correctly or not and when was the record updated.
so I have table 1 which contains my data been worked upon and to be lookedup with DB.
basically, am unioning all records from the DB and applying ranking then lookup with my table1 been worked upon.
record could have been changed many times, I need the latest date so I applied ranking. can you please help in correcting this. as am not able to get desired results

```
select a.*, b.update_dt||' '||c.udpate_dt|| as update_date
from table1 a
left join
 ( select distinct customer_id, max(last_updated_dt) as update_dt
   qualify rank() over(partition by customer_id order by Last_updated_dt) as rank
   from table2
   group by customer_id
 ) b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id

left join
 ( select distinct customer_id, max(last_updated_dt) as update_dt
   qualify rank() over(partition by customer_id order by last_updated_dt) as rank
   from table3
   group by customer_id
 )c
on a.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Comment: bit of urgent, if someone can help in this would be great for me. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either `max(last_updated_dt)` or `QUALIFY`, but not both:

```
select a.*, b.update_dt||' '||c.udpate_dt|| as update_date
from table1 a
left join
 ( select customer_id, max(last_updated_dt) as update_dt
   from table2
   group by customer_id
 ) b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id

left join
 ( select customer_id, max(last_updated_dt) as update_dt
   from table3
   group by customer_id
 )c
on a.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

If you need other columns besides the max date:

```
select a.*, b.update_dt||' '||c.udpate_dt|| as update_date
from table1 a
left join
 ( select customer_id, last_updated_dt as update_dt, ...
   from table2
   qualify row_number() over(partition by customer_id 
                       order by last_updated_dt DESC) = 1
 ) b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id

left join
 ( select customer_id, last_updated_dt as update_dt, ...
   from table3
   qualify row_number() over(partition by customer_id 
                       order by last_updated_dt DESC) = 1
 )c
on a.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one question - like a transaction were updated thrice and I need the most updated date. Row_number would do? or Rank?

Comment: @puneetmadan: `ROW_NUMBER` is guaranteed to assign unique values (if there are multiple updates for the same date one will be choosen randomly), but `RANK` will assign the same value for the same date, thus returning all rows for the last date (similar to the `MAX` version).